# nodejs mysql variable access after promise

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm beginner into nodeJS world and i try to connect a mysql database. I first select a team (equipe) and after that i have to select all the members of this team.

Finally, i want to construct an array with my teams and the members (in the lesEquipes var). When the code comes to the 3rd then, my var is null ! WHY please ?

Here is my code :

```
    class Database {
        constructor() {
            this.connection = mysql.createConnection({
                host: "192.x.x.x",
                user: "john",
                password: "mypass",
                database: "mybase"
              });
        }
        query(sql, args) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                this.connection.query(sql, args, (err, result, fields) => {
                    if (err) return reject(err);

                    resolve (result);
                });
            });
        }

        close() {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                this.connection.end(err => {
                    if (err) return reject (err);

                    resolve();
                });
            });
        }
    }

    var database = new Database();

.............

app.post('/visu',function(req,res){
    //console.log(nodedump(req.params.mdp));
    //console.log(req.body);
    // codage en dur de l'authentification

    if((req.body.email == "john@gmail.com") && (req.body.mdp == "password")){
        var leUser = "administrateur";

    let lesEquipes = new Array();

    let test = 'Toto';

    database.query("select * from equipe order by id")
      .then( result => {



        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            let courante = new Array();
            let nomEquipe = result[i].nomEquipe;
            let idEquipe = result[i].id;
            courante[0] = result[i];

            var sql2 = "select * from participant where equipe = " + result[i].id;
            //console.log(sql2);

            database.query(sql2)
            .then(result2 => {
                console.log("Membres de l'équipe : " + nomEquipe);
                courante[1] = result2;
                console.log("COURANTE 2 "+ JSON.stringify(courante));
                lesEquipes[idEquipe] = courante;

                let test = 'AUTRE CHOSE';
                /*
                console.log("QUERY 2 "+ JSON.stringify(result2));
                for (var j = 0; j < result2.length; j++) {

                  participant = result2[j].nom;
                  console.log(participant);
                }
                */
                //res.render('visuEquipes.ejs', { user:leUser, equipes:lesEquipes});
                //console.log("Contenu "+ JSON.stringify(lesEquipes));
                return ""; //database.query(sql3);
            });
        }
        console.log("Contenu "+ JSON.stringify(test));
        console.log("Contenu "+ JSON.stringify(lesEquipes));
    }).then(result3 =>{
        console.log("result 3 : "+result3);
        console.log("Contenu "+ JSON.stringify(test));
    **// THIS VAR IS NULL NULL NULL lesEquipes
        console.log("Contenu "+ JSON.stringify(lesEquipes));**
        res.render('visuEquipes.ejs', { user:leUser, equipes : lesEquipes});  
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        database.close();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are executing asynchronous code inside a loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
  /**/
  database.query(sql2).then(result2 => {
    /**/
  });
}
```

So in `.then(result3 =>{` the variable `lesEquipes` is very likely to have not been initialized.

You have to wait for all the promises to resolve. You can easly add an array of promises.

```
const promises = [];
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
   promises.push(database.query(sql2).then(result2 => {/*...*/}));
}
return Promise.all(promises);
```

Or you can use `async-p` library to iterate the array, or better you can use ES7 `async-await` constructs.

Comment: Great ! It works fine with the array of promises. Thank you very much !